# Pass Div ID to jquery/ajax to display a message for each specific user

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a page where I retrieve and display details of each client.
There is an option for users to update the status of each client.

Currently I use `ajax` to update the status of each client so the page wont be refreshed.

Only problem with this is that I have a status column where status of the client is displayed and as the page doesn't get refreshed the status of client is changed in the database but this does not reflect/show on the page.

I have tried to overcome this problem without success.

Does anyone know how I could achieve this?

My current script:

```
function processForm(formId) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'form_process.php',
        data: $("#" + formId).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {




            var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
            var $div = $row.find("div.msg");
            $div.css("background", "#f00");
            $div.html(data);
        }
    });
}​;​
```

and HTML:

```
<table width="787" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>FORM 1</td>

      <td>
        <div id='msg' class='msg'></div>
      </td>

      <td>
        <form action="" name="form1" id="form1" method="post" onsubmit=
        "processForm('form1');return false;">
          <input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" value="" /> <input type=
          "text" name="surname" id="surname" value="" /> <input type="submit" name=
          "submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>FORM2</td>

      <td>
        <div id='msg' class='msg'></div>
      </td>

      <td>
        <form action="" name="form2" id="form2" method="post" onsubmit=
        "processForm('form2');return false;">
          <input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" value="" /> <input type=
          "text" name="surname" id="surname" value="" /> <input type="submit" name=
          "submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>

      <td>&nbsp;</td>

      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `$div.html(data);` - you're best to `console.log(data)` and see what part of `data` you actually need....

Comment: What do you think `this` represents in the success callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try constructing the HTML like this:

```
<table id="clientDetails" width="787" border="1">
<tr>
<td>FORM 1</td>
<td class='msg'></td>
<td><form>
<input type="text" name="user_name" value="" />
<input type="text" name="surname" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>FORM2</td>
<td class='msg'></td>
<td><form>
<input type="text" name="user_name" value="" />
<input type="text" name="surname" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And the javascript like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#clientDetails").on('submit', 'form', function() {
        var $form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'form_process.php',
            data: $form.serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                $form.closest("tr").find(".msg").css("background", "#f00").html(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

This at least stands a chance of working but is also more efficient in that submit event handling is delegated to the table with just one event handler in total instead of one per form ... plus associated simplification of the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Just stay at what you are.. You have to just simply call your function on document ready event..

Like this..

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    //pass formid
    processForm(clientDetails)

});
</script>
```

Hope this will help...

otherwise Beetroot-Beetroot help is also work.